# Use Ajax to update the value of two dropdowns filters C# MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

i've developed an mvc web app where i have a table with datas that i can filter with two dropdowns (one where i can select the value state of a data, and the other where i can select the value if the data is closed or not - yes/no) i can select both of them and if i press the button submit to filter it works. Now i want to implement some ajax calls like when i select a value of one of the dropdowns automatically update the result table but i can't pass the value of the dropdown to the controller, can anyone help me, thanks

```
<table  id="tb2">    
    <tr>
        <th>
            <h4> LIST : @Html.DropDownList("stato", "ALL ")</h4>
        </th>
        <th>
            <h4>ARCHVIED : @Html.DropDownList("closed", "ALL ")</h4>
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-info" />
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Filter(string stato,  string closed)
    {
        List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();

        List<Closed> closedList = new List<Closed>();
        closedList.Add(new Closed("False"));
        closedList.Add(new Closed("True"));
        ViewBag.stato = new SelectList(myApi.GetState(), "Name", "Name");
        ViewBag.closed = new SelectList(closedList, "Id", "Name");

        if ((stato != null && stato != "") || (closed != null && closed != ""))
        {
            foreach (var card in model)
            {
                if (card.IdList == stato || stato == "")
                {
                    if (card.Closed == closed || closed == "")
                    {
                        cards.Add(card);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(cards);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

this is my jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var drpdown1 = $("#Dropdown1Id");
var drpdown2 = $("#Dropdown1Id");
drpdown1.on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: " /Select/Filter",
        data: { stato: drpdown1.val(), closed: drpdown2.val() },
        success: function (res) {
            var dropValue1 = drpdown1.val();
            var dropValue2 = drpdown2.val();
            stato = dropValue1;
            closed = dropValue2;
        }
    })
})
});
```

But it's not working, i'm new to ajax and need some help

Comment: Please Add your jQuery code.

Comment: Here we like to help to fix issue. Please provide your attempt. You can improve your question by using this guide "How do I ask a good question?" here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i've updated my question, can you please see if it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

Change your html give a method on button click. Give Id for both drop down and then write ajax function like bellow

```
function YourMethod() {
        var drpdown1= $("#Dropdown1Id").val();
        var drpdown2= $("#Dropdown2Id").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/ControllerName/Filter",
            data: { stato: drpdown1,closed:drpdown2},
            success: function(res) {
               //Your work here                      
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: i want to remove the submit botton and use only the change value of the dropdown

Comment: Then Just add onChange YourMethod on your dropdown